# Alternativa a delay() al programar micro STM32 en lenguaje C

Tags: c, arm

Hola a todos y gracias por pasarse por acá.

Mi duda es bastante sencilla ya que soy novato programando micros en C. Quisiera saber como reemplazar la sentencia delay() en mi código, de manera que sea posible activar "x" cosa en un momento dado, seguir ejecutando código para generar la solución de "y" cosa, y volver a cambiar el estado de "x" cosa en otro momento dado sin detener la ejecución del código. Por ejemplo, digamos que tengo 4 leds y un oscilador a 20hz, con eso quiero que en el pulso numero 5 se active el led1, luego en el pulso 10 que se desactive el led1 y se active el led2, luego que en el pulso 12 se activen el led3 y led4, luego en el pulso 15 que se desactive el led3 y por ultimo que en el pulso 20 se desactive el led4. Espero haberme explicado, agradezco sus comentarios.

Saludos desde Panamá.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no te preocupes seguro que poco a poco irás aprendiendo conceptos y esto te resultará mucho más sencillo.

No se si sabes lo que son las interrupciones pero son mecanismos básicos para programar microcontroladores, en las que puedes ejecutar una acción en función de un evento, y mientras podrá estar realizando otras tareas.

En el problema que tu planteas, puedes hacer que salte una interrupción cada vez que tu oscilador tiene un flanco de subida y en la interrupción incrementar un contador. Después, en tu programa principal , en función de ese contador realizar una acción u otra en función del valor del contador, así el micro podrá seguir realizando tareas entre interrupción e interrupción.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias Juan José, utilizaré las interrupciones ya que se adapta a lo que necesito. Saludos

Comment: De nada, si sigues teniendo alguna duda, puedes ponerla por aquí sin problema.